# Can't eliminate margins on all side of a toolbar in android

Tags: android, xml, layout, toolbar

I'm trying to include a toolbar widget into an activity, but, the toolbar has extra spacing on all sides.

**toolbar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    local:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    local:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    local:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    local:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    />
```

**Preview of toolbar.xml:**

[image]

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.infotoall.newsapp.FacebookLoginActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Preview of layout:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove **Padding** from your **Linear Layout**.
 Remove these lines

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the XML for your Activity and remove the padding attributes. The Activity is the holder for your toolbar and thus the padding attributes will apply for to all of it's child elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are providing paddings in the root `LinearLayout` of `activity_main.xml`.Change your `activity_main.xml` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"   
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.infotoall.newsapp.FacebookLoginActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```